My dropdown taking 100vw but creating horizontal overflow on the right side of window
I am developing a custom Navbar. The Menu is not opening correctly. It has 100vw but going to the right side of the window creates a horizontal scroll. I have 2 components Navbar and Menu. The menu component is called inside Navbar.
This is the screenshot my screen.

I think the problem is with the parent component's CSS. Kindly help me out.
Navbar Component
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Logo from "../../assets/images/logo.png"
import LogoHover from "../../assets/images/logo-hover.png"
import styles from "./Navbar.module.css"
import { FaCaretDown, FaCaretUp, FaSearch, FaGlobe } from "react-icons/fa"
import Menu from "../menu/Menu"

const Navbar = () => {
  const [logoHover, setLogoHover] = useState(false)

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className={styles.logo_container}>
        <img
          onMouseEnter={() => setLogoHover(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setLogoHover(false)}
          className={styles.logo}
          src={!logoHover ? Logo : LogoHover}
          alt="Logo"
        />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.main_links}>
        <Menu title="What we do">
          <div>
            <h1>What we do</h1>
            <div>
              <small>sasads</small>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
              <p>paragraph</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Menu>

        <div className={styles.link}>
          <p>What we do</p>
          <FaCaretDown />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.link}>
          <p>What we think</p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.link}>
          <p>Who we are</p>
          <FaCaretDown />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.link}>
          <p>Careers</p>
          <FaCaretDown />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.country_select}>
        <FaSearch />
        <div className={styles.link}>
          <FaGlobe />
          <div className={styles.link}>
            <p>UAE</p>
            <FaCaretDown />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navbar



nav {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.main_links {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
  align-items: center;
}

.link:hover {
  color: #a2a2a0;
}

.country_select {
  display: flex;
  gap: 25px;
}

.logo_container {
  width: 20%;
  .logo {
    transition: transform 1s ease;
  }
}

.logo:hover {
  transition: transform 2s ease;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}



Menu Component
import React, { useState } from "react"
import styles from "./Menu.module.css"
import { FaCaretDown, FaCaretUp } from "react-icons/fa"

const Menu = ({ title, children }) => {
  const [dropdownVisible, setDropdownVisible] = useState(false)

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setDropdownVisible(!dropdownVisible)
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.menu}>
      <div className={styles.link} onClick={toggleDropdown}>
        <p>{title}</p>
        {dropdownVisible ? <FaCaretUp /> : <FaCaretDown />}
      </div>
      <div className={`${styles.dropdown} ${dropdownVisible && styles.open}`}>
        <div className={styles.dropdown_content}>{children}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Menu



.menu {
  position: relative;
}

.link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #202020;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  max-height: 0;
}

.dropdown_content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.open {
  max-height: 85vh;
}




As the class .menu has a position: relative; the absolute position under for .dropdown is calculated from the position of the .menu. Try without the position: relative;.

I have tried this but its not working. I am handling the position of the child element (dropdown) from its parent (menu) using position relative. If I remove the position relative from there, then I can't handle the position of the dropdown.

Because you put a 100vwwidth to your .dropdown, you can either put a static sixe or a max-content with a padding, or if you absolutely want to make it that large you can just use a calc(100vw - <the distance to your nav button> (with a min-width fixed) but that's a bit overkill and it will not be a simple mesure as you put a space-evenlyin the repartition of your nav links. Honestly if you change the width to a static value it will arrange everything so don't put that much effort into that.

Either you want the .dropdown to be just under the nav link and it has to have a width fixed, either you want the .dropdown to be as large as the window and it and it can keep the width: 100vw; but you have to remove the position: relative; from the .menu. Even for UI/UX consistency.

Thanks @canelle. The issue was with position relative, as the dropdown was taking width relative to its parent i.e menu. Removing the position relative and handling position of dropdown from the window solved that issue.

@HamzaIlyas so the question can be closed with this solution if it's ok now :)
